# MongoDB php Parsing to Json Style Output

Tags: php, mongodb, parsing

Iam currently reading the data from MongoDB using PHP and the following PHP ouput from my program as shown below needs to be converted JSON style output as shown below

**Mongo DB PHP output**

> Array ( [_id] => MongoId Object ( [$id] => 53481398834269e8e25fa268 )
>   [category] => 2014-04-01 [value1] => 400 [value2] => 200 ) Array (
>   [_id] => MongoId Object ( [$id] => 534813a9834269e8e25fa269 )
>   [category] => 2014-04-02 [value1] => 405 [value2] => 205 ) Array (
>   [_id] => MongoId Object ( [$id] => 534813d7834269e8e25fa26a )
>   [category] => 2014-04-03 [value1] => 408 [value2] => 211 ) Array (
>   [_id] => MongoId Object ( [$id] => 534813ec834269e8e25fa26b )
>   [category] => 2014-04-04 [value1] => 418 [value2] => 198 ) Array (
>   [_id] => MongoId Object ( [$id] => 53481402834269e8e25fa26c )
>   [category] => 2014-04-05 [value1] => 370 [value2] => 221 ) Array (
>   [_id] => MongoId Object ( [$id] => 53481439834269e8e25fa26d )
>   [category] => 2014-04-06 [value1] => 299 [value2] => 180 ) Array (
>   [_id] => MongoId Object ( [$id] => 5348144e834269e8e25fa26e )
>   [category] => 2014-04-07 [value1] => 311 [value2] => 224 ) Array (
>   [_id] => MongoId Object ( [$id] => 53481461834269e8e25fa26f )
>   [category] => 2014-04-08 [value1] => 315 [value2] => 254 ) Array (
>   [_id] => MongoId Object ( [$id] => 5348146f834269e8e25fa270 )
>   [category] => 2014-04-09 [value1] => 325 [value2] => 264 ) Array (
>   [_id] => MongoId Object ( [$id] => 5348147f834269e8e25fa271 )
>   [category] => 2014-04-10 [value1] => 335 [value2] => 255 ) Array (
>   [_id] => MongoId Object ( [$id] => 5348148c834269e8e25fa272 )
>   [category] => 2014-04-11 [value1] => 365 [value2] => 265 )

**JSON Style PHP Out**

> [ { "category": "2013-08-24", "value1": 417, "value2": 127 }, {
>   "category": "2013-08-25", "value1": 417, "value2": 356 }, {
>   "category": "2013-08-26", "value1": 531, "value2": 585 }, {
>   "category": "2013-08-27", "value1": 333, "value2": 910 }, {
>   "category": "2013-08-28", "value1": 552, "value2": 30 }, { "category":
>   "2013-08-29", "value1": 492, "value2": 371 }, { "category":
>   "2013-08-30", "value1": 379, "value2": 781 }, { "category":
>   "2013-08-31", "value1": 767, "value2": 494 }, { "category":
>   "2013-09-01", "value1": 169, "value2": 364 }, { "category":
>   "2013-09-02", "value1": 314, "value2": 476 }, { "category":
>   "2013-09-03", "value1": 437, "value2": 759 } ]

Requires Expert help

Comment: so what is the problem? are you asking how to encode the JSON? or you want to reformat the data structure?

Comment: reformat the data structure as the JSON style output as shown above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to loop through the array and rebuild it the way you need it before encoding:

```
$data_to_encode = array();
foreach($mongo_objects as $mongo){
    $data['category'] = $mongo['category'];
    $data['value1'] = $mongo['value1'];
    $data['value2'] = $mongo['value2'];
    $data_to_encode[] = $data;
}

$json = json_encode($data_to_encode);
```

---

If you want less variables:

```
$data = array();
foreach($mongo_objects as $mongo){
    $data[] = array('category'=>$mongo['category'],
                    'value1'=>$mongo['value1'],
                    'value2'=>$mongo['value2'],
              );
}

$json = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Here is the reformatted output http://marketcalls.in/dev/mongo1.php however little close to the required json style output

Comment: @RajandranR oops, I had a mistake, I fixed it

Comment: That worked like a chart here is the final output www.marketcalls.in/dev/mongo1 and now the amcharts are showing good www.marketcalls.in/test-charts

Comment: Thanks a lot. Was breaking my head for the past two days!

Answer (score 0):

```
$json_output = json_encode($MongoDBPHPoutput, true);
```

Comment: Hi yes it worked but this comes with the "_ID" variables too. Any idea how to remove it here is my output http://marketcalls.in/dev/mongo.php

Comment: do you mind telling us why you wouldnt want the id? you can just ignore it, maybe you have a reason for that?

Comment: Currently trying to implement amcharts. Here is a sample demo using http://www.marketcalls.in/test-charts which get the feeds from http://www.marketcalls.in/dev/data.php (php output of mysql). However i need the same sort with php output of mongodb http://marketcalls.in/dev/mongo.php as iam planning to replace the database as mongoDB

Comment: I see what you mean , please see if my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23033684/1880431) help